# How to store the addresses of different unordered map into another unordered map and then use them for by referencing?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, parameters, unordered-map

I save integer values in 2 different unordered_map, say, map1 and map2. Now, I save the address of these maps into another master unordered map,say, arr_maps using some key already defined. Now, I want to access the corresponding map based on the value of the key. The value is the memory address of map1/map2. I pass these addresses to a function to access them because I don't to copy the whole map into another map, just wanna reference it. I am not able to do that. Getting no reference the map but the code is building

I have tried referencing but it doesn't work

```
 **#header files here** 

 unordered_map<string, unordered_map<ui,ui>*> arr_map; //Global declaration

 function test(unordered_map<ui,ui>& cmap)
 {
   ui deg_index;

   unordered_map<ui, ui>::const_iterator get = cmap.find(0);
   //"0" is present in cmap, but not able to reference the map

   if(get_node_deg == curr_node_deg.end())
    //do something
 }

 main()
 {
   unordered_map<ui, ui> map1,map2;

   map1.emplace(0,0);
   map1.emplace(1,1);
   arr_map.emplace("01",&map1);

   map2.emplace(0,1);
   map2.emplace(1,2);
   arr_map.emplace("12",&map2);

   test(arr_map["01"]);//not able to reference it
   // want to pass the reference of map 1 and use it, instead of copying the whole map

   test(arr_map["12"]);//same here
 }
```